# What XSL Scheme to convert this XML?

Tags: xml, xslt, converters, transform

I am exporting datebase from Access in that looking XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2014-05-11T15:51:32">
    <Mnc_x0020_172>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <package_id>minecraft</package_id>
        <cat>lib</cat>
        <www>#http://minecraft.net/#</www>
        <nazwa>Minecraft</nazwa>
        <author>Mojang</author>
        <opis>Game - build your own world!</opis>
        <img>#/mc.png#</img>
    </Mnc_x0020_172>
    <Mnc_x0020_172>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <package_id>modloader</package_id>
        <cat>lib</cat>
        <www>#http://minecraftforum.net/topic/75440-x/#</www>
        <nazwa>ModLoader</nazwa>
        <author>Risugami</author>
        <opis>ModLoader - library to load mods</opis>
        <img>#/gen.png#</img>
    </Mnc_x0020_172>
    ...
</dataroot>
```

And so on.

I want to convert it to this kind:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <package id="minecraft" cat="lib">
        <nazwa>Minecraft</nazwa>
        <author>Mojang</author>
        <www>http://minecraft.net/</www>
        <opis>Game - build your own world!</opis>
        <img>/mc.png</img>
    </package>
    <package id="modloader" cat="lib">
        <nazwa>ModLoader</nazwa>
        <author>Risugami</author>
        <www>http://minecraftforum.net/topic/75440-x/</www>
        <opis>ModLoader - library to load mods</opis>
        <img>/gen.png</img>
    </package>
...
```

And so on.

What XSLT code use to transform it?

I haven't use it before so I am blank about it. I wrote smth like that for now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="ID">

        <xsd:element name="cat" type="catType"/>
          <xsd:complexType name="catType">
             <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="nazwa"      type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="author"     type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="opis"       type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="www"        type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="img"        type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="depends"    type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="conflicts"  type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="after"      type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="replaces"   type="xsd:string"/>
             </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <xsd:attribute name="package id" type="xsd:string"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="package_id/cd">
            <xsl:value-of select="cat"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are mixing XSD (XML Schema - which is used to describe and validate one or more XML instances) with XSLT (a functional template-based language used to transform a XML instance into another format). Perhaps you should read a bit about them. To make the transformation you want, you only need XSLT, and you should declare templates to match nodes in your *source* document and write them with the structure you want in your *result* document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XSL transform applied on the source XML you provided will generate the expected result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="dataroot">
        <xml><xsl:apply-templates/></xml>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Mnc_x0020_172">
        <package id="{package_id}" cat="{cat}">
            <nazwa><xsl:value-of select="nazwa"/></nazwa>
            <author><xsl:value-of select="author"/></author>
            <www><xsl:value-of select="translate(www,'#','')"/></www>
            <opis><xsl:value-of select="opis"/></opis>
            <img><xsl:value-of select="translate(img,'#','')"/></img>
        </package>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `match` attribute in each `xsl:template` matches a node in your *source* document using XPath. The first template matches the `dataroot` node, adds a `<xml>...</xml>` root node to the output and calls for the processing of the other templates. The second template will match a nodeset formed by your two `Mnc-x0020_172` nodes, will generate a `<package>` element for each one and will select the nodes from your source (in context) and place them in an element of the same name. `translate` is used to remove the `#`.

There are other ways to obtain the same results. If you didn't have a namespace declaration, you could have used `<xsl:copy-of select="node">` to copy the nodes that are identical on both documents.

Comment: This Source XML is the export from Access.
And I notice there is option to use schema to export that xml

Comment: Paste your source document and the above XSLT code in http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html and you'll see that it generates the code you require. XML-Schema is not used for transformation, but you can write or generate one for your result or source XML if necessary.

Comment: one more question:
how if I have another line like 
<replaces>modloader audiomod</replaces> 
in source XML and want to make it in two lines like 
<replaces>modloader</replaces> 
<replaces>audiomod</replaces>